# Run external process from groovy

Tags: bash, groovy, external-process

i have a bash script which i want to execute from groovy like

```
some_shell_script.sh param1 "report_date=`some_function 0 \"%Y%m%d\"`"
```

that script runs successfully from the command line, but when i try to execute it from Groovy

```
def command = "some_shell_script.sh param1 "report_date=`some_function 0 \"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S\"`""
def sout = new StringBuffer()
def serr = new StringBuffer()
//tried to use here different shells /bin/sh /bin/bash bash 
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(['sh', '-c',command])
Process proc = pb.start()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)

def status = proc.waitFor()

println 'sout: ' + sout
println 'serr: ' + serr
```

i have the following error

```
serr: sh: some_function: command not found
```

at the same time

```
which some_function
```

returns functional definition like

```
some_function ()
{
;some definition here
}
```

looks like when i run external script from groovy it start different process without context of parent process. I mean no function definitions of parent process are exists.

Anyone have cue how to cope with such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely check out those quotes as indicated by @Reimeus.  I had some doubts about those.

In addition, `some_function()` may be defined in `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` or in a file sourced by either of those when you run bash interactively.  This does not happen if you run a script.
(Which is good for making script run predictably - you can't have your script depend on people's login environment.)

If this is the case, move some_function() to another file, and put its full path in the BASH_ENV variable, so that bash picks it up when processing scripts.

man bash:

```
   When  bash  is  started  non-interactively,  to run a shell script, for
   example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands
   its  value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name
   of a file to read and execute.  Bash behaves as if the  following  com-
   mand were executed:
```

```sh
          if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
```

```
   but  the  value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the file
   name.
   [Manual page bash(1) line 158]
```

Comment: not sure that this is related but **export -f some_function** prior groovy session solved the problem

Comment: This will work for your login environment.  The `export -f` forces the function definition into the environment of the script, which in turn passes it on to the bash instance created by ProcessBuilder.  *Beware*, if you give the groovy script to others, their environment may not have your definition of `some_function`.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace the double quotes in your command definition with single quotes.

`` def command = 'some_shell_script.sh param1 "report_date=`some_function 0 "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`' ``

Add:

```
println command
```

to ensure that you are executing the correct command.

Also open a new bash shell and ensure that `some_function` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a path problem.  Can you put the full path to the script and try again?

Comment: looks like it defined in profiles. i don't know the path, which returns function definition, but not the path

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER:** there are limitations with *this* solution, **and,** the shell sub-script commands should be properly tested before deployment. However if multithreading were not required *e.g.* the *function* provides immediately some short results, there is an alternative as I implemented in [here](http://code.google.com/p/blu-strglr-grovecell/source/browse/Grovecell/src/net/strglr/blu/doctool/taglet_module.groovy#564).

*For instance*, if the result of `mycmd` depends on an environment variable set in `~/.bashrc` I could display its result: (tried as a groovy-script/v1.8.1, and yes, this is a stupid example and it might be risky!)

```
commands = '''source ~/.bashrc; cd ~/mytest; ./mycmd'''
"bash".execute().with{
  out << commands
  out << ';exit $?\n'
  waitFor()
  [ok:!exitValue(), out:in.text, err:err.text]
}.with{ println ok?out:err }
```